# Necessary condition for convergence of improper integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

If $\int_A^{+\infty}f(x)\, dx$ is convergent, can we deduce that $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=0$

If **true**, is there any limitation to the value of $A$ or $f(x)$? If **false**, why?

I just started learning calculus, so forgive me for asking such an elementary question. I didn't find relevant information on my textbook.

Comment: Take $f$ identically zero, except for triangles of height one and base getting smaller very fast.

Comment: This is a very common false belief, as NDB shows

Comment: @NDB thank u guys. But I wonder will it be true under a particular condition. Could u plz take another look at my comment below the answer? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be given by
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
2 & \text{if $2<x<2+\frac{1}{8}$} \\
3 & \text{if $3<x<3+\frac{1}{27}$} \\
4 & \text{if $4<x<4+\frac{1}{64}$} \\
\vdots \\
n & \text{if $n<x<n+\frac{1}{n^3}$} \\
\vdots \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Then $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx = 2\cdot\frac{1}{8} + 3\cdot\frac{1}{27} + 4\cdot\frac{1}{64} + \cdots = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{16} + \cdots < \infty$ but $\lim_{x\to\infty} |f(x)| = \infty.$

This function is discontinuous, but a continuous function can be created by replacing the "plateaus" with some kind of bumps.

Comment: when $f(x)$ is a $(+-*/)$ combination of elementary functions, and it's continous and **NOT** piecewise, will the statement be true? e.g. $f(x)=\frac{e^xsin(2x)}{x^2−3x+1}$ (with proper value added when denominator is $0$)

Comment: @Cyrus. I'm sure that it's possible to construct an example similar to the one I gave by using elementary functions.

Comment: thank u. great help.